# Export HTML data to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

On my UI where I have A HTML table and some Input fields, all the fields have some data including table so what I am trying to do is :-

I want to export HTML full page data into excel,all input fields as well as table data, earlier I was using `table2excel` plugin but it is only exporting the HTML table data not input fields data

**Code**

```js
var tableValue = [{
    "Name": "vivek",
    "Class": "12",
    "English": 89,
    "Maths": 45,
    "Physics": 63
  },
  {
    "Name": "Raul",
    "Class": "11",
    "English": 55,
    "Maths": 45,
    "Physics": 23
  },
  {
    "Name": "Sam",
    "Class": "12",
    "English": 55,
    "Maths": 68,
    "Physics": 56
  },
  {
    "Name": "Arun",
    "Class": "12",
    "English": 45,
    "Maths": 78,
    "Physics": 58
  },
  {
    "Name": "Patric",
    "Class": "12",
    "English": 86,
    "Maths": 45,
    "Physics": 62
  },



]

function addTable(tableValue) {
  var $tbl = $("<table />", {
      "class": "table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
    }),
    $thd = $("<thead/>"),
    $tb = $("<tbody/>"),
    $trh = $("<tr/>", {
      "class": "text-center"
    });

  $.each(Object.keys(tableValue[0]), function(_, val) {
    $("<th/>").html(val).appendTo($trh);
  });
  $trh.appendTo($thd);
  $.each(tableValue, function(_, item) {
    $tr = $("<tr/>");
    $.each(item, function(key, value) {
      if (typeof(value) === 'number') {
        $("<td/>", {
          "class": "text-right"
        }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
      } else {
        $("<td/>", {
          "class": "text-left"
        }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
      }

      $tr.appendTo($tb);


    });
  });
  $tbl.append($thd).append($tb);
  $("#grnReportTable").html($tbl);



}
$("#supplierAddReport").val("STILL FLOOR, NO. 34, 2ND CROSS, SWASTHI ROAD, SHANTINAGAR, BANGALORE, 560027 Contact Name: SURESH, Contact No. 22745206 GST No. : 29210085111, Email Id: ALPINEPRODUCTS@GMAIL.COM")
addTable(tableValue)

$("#export").click(function() {
  $("#grnReportTable").table2excel({
    filename: "Data"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">


  <div class="container" id="grnReportTable"></div>

  <div class="form-row">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <label for="mrk1">Marks 1</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="mrk1" id="mrk1" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="50">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <label for="mrk2">Marks 2</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="mrk2" id="mrk2" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="50.22">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <label for="mrk3">Marks3</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" name="mrk3" id="mrk3" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="43">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
      <label for="supplierAddReport">Suppl. Address</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" readonly="readonly" name="supplierAddReport" id="supplierAddReport"></textarea>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="export" class="btn btn-default commonButton">
  <i class='fas fa-file-export'></i>&nbsp;Export
 </button>
```

```
<script
    src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
```

The table to excel plugin only export HTML table but I want to export Full page Data here i am only showing input fields but in my actual code I have some text areas as well as `select option`

i want to export it like [image: This]

Comment: Use the database js plugin https://datatables.net/

Comment: @Omi that will only export  HTML table not other data

Comment: you can customize the export button

Comment: @Omi customize export button ? didn't get you

Comment: Xfer this link https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38784/how-to-add-a-custom-row-at-the-bottom-of-excel-export

Comment: @Omi hey can you help me with some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of convert html to excel, change your scenario to convert JSON to CSV. Because, you have data and your data is JSON, that can convert to html table or CSV or other types, and solution of JSON to CSV is better than html to excel.
First: Prepare data.That means convert your data to your schema, you wanted export.

```
var tableValue = [
  { // Row for Marks 1
    "Name": "Marks 1",
    "Class": "50",
    "English": "",
    "Maths": "",
    "Physics": ""
  },
  { // Row for Marks 2
    "Name": "Marks 2",
    "Class": "55.22",
    "English": "",
    "Maths": "",
    "Physics": ""
  },
  { // Row for Marks 3
    "Name": "Marks 3",
    "Class": "43",
    "English": "",
    "Maths": "",
    "Physics": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "",
    "Class": "",
    "English": "",
    "Maths": "",
    "Physics": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name",
    "Class": "Class",
    "English": "English",
    "Maths": "Maths",
    "Physics": "Physics"
  },
  {
    "Name": "vivek",
    "Class": "12",
    "English": 89,
    "Maths": 45,
    "Physics": 63
  },
  {
    "Name": "Raul",
    "Class": "11",
    "English": 55,
    "Maths": 45,
    "Physics": 23
  },
  {
    "Name": "Sam",
    "Class": "12",
    "English": 55,
    "Maths": 68,
    "Physics": 56
  },
  {
    "Name": "Arun",
    "Class": "12",
    "English": 45,
    "Maths": 78,
    "Physics": 58
  },
  {
    "Name": "Patric",
    "Class": "12",
    "English": 86,
    "Maths": 45,
    "Physics": 62
  }
]
```

, now You do not need any additional library, use this code :

```
// JAVASCRIPT
function convertToCSV(objArray) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','

            line += array[i][index];
        }

        str += line + '\r\n';
    }

    return str;
}

function exportCSVFile(headers, items, fileTitle) {
    if (headers) {
        items.unshift(headers);
    }

    // Convert Object to JSON
    var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);

    var csv = this.convertToCSV(jsonObject);

    var exportedFilenmae = fileTitle + '.csv' || 'export.csv';

    var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilenmae);
    } else {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
            // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.setAttribute("href", url);
            link.setAttribute("download", exportedFilenmae);
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    }
}

function download(){
  var headers = {
      Name: '', // remove commas to avoid errors
      Class: '',
      English: '',
      Maths: '',
      Physics: ''
  };

  itemsNotFormatted = [
  {
    "Name": "Marks 1",
    "Class": "50",
    "English": "",
    "Maths": "",
    "Physics": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "Marks 2",
    "Class": "55.22",
    "English": "",
    "Maths": "",
    "Physics": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "Marks 3",
    "Class": "43",
    "English": "",
    "Maths": "",
    "Physics": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "",
    "Class": "",
    "English": "",
    "Maths": "",
    "Physics": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "Name",
    "Class": "Class",
    "English": "English",
    "Maths": "Maths",
    "Physics": "Physics"
  },
  {
    "Name": "vivek",
    "Class": "12",
    "English": 89,
    "Maths": 45,
    "Physics": 63
  },
  {
    "Name": "Raul",
    "Class": "11",
    "English": 55,
    "Maths": 45,
    "Physics": 23
  },
  {
    "Name": "Sam",
    "Class": "12",
    "English": 55,
    "Maths": 68,
    "Physics": 56
  },
  {
    "Name": "Arun",
    "Class": "12",
    "English": 45,
    "Maths": 78,
    "Physics": 58
  },
  {
    "Name": "Patric",
    "Class": "12",
    "English": 86,
    "Maths": 45,
    "Physics": 62
  }
];

  var itemsFormatted = [];

  // format the data
  itemsNotFormatted.forEach((item) => {
      itemsFormatted.push({
          Name: item.Name, // remove commas to avoid errors,
          Class: item.Class,
          English: item.English,
          Maths: item.Maths,
          Physics: item.Physics
      });
  });

  var fileTitle = 'SCORES'; // or 'my-unique-title'

  exportCSVFile(headers, itemsFormatted, fileTitle); // call the exportCSVFile() function to process the JSON and trigger the download
}
```

// HTML CODE

```
<div class="download-wrapper" onClick="download()">
  <p><i class="material-icons">file_download</i></p>
  <p>Download Demo CSV File</p>
</div>
```

```html
<p class="codepen" data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-default-tab="js,result" data-user="danny_pule" data-slug-hash="WRgqNx" style="height: 265px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;" data-pen-title="JSON to CSV">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/danny_pule/pen/WRgqNx/">
  JSON to CSV</a> by Danny Pule (<a href="https://codepen.io/danny_pule">@danny_pule</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

// RESULT
[image]

Comment: So you are saying that I should create a JSON and then export that to csv, but In my code I have a address text field that have little lengthy data, so that may cause issue while creating the JSON format

Comment: That's not important. You must try to convert suitable Json data.

Comment: hey I have added a `textarea` field can you please help me out with what should be the `JSON` format for that? after that I will create the `JSON` of required Format

Comment: For textarea, first ```var textvValue = $('textaread').html()```
And create row, like this:
```{
    "Name": "textarea",
    "Class": textvValue,
    "English": "",
    "Maths": "",
    "Physics": ""
  },```
and add to **JSON**.

Comment: ya that is working fine the only issue is to add textarea into JSON I am not able to think about JSON format, just check my edit once there I have a textarea  and It has address so little bit confused what will be the format and how it will render on excel

Comment: For textarea try this : first var textValue = $('textarea').val() And create row, like this: { "Name": "Suppl. Address", "Class": textValue, "English": "", "Maths": "", "Physics": "" } , And add to json

Comment: @viveksingh how you want show exported data? in the other word, Where do you want to put Textarea ?